# Daemon dies but upstart thinks it is still running

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, upstart

If the daemon process dies, I'm unable to restart it manually: `start foo` results in a message that "start: Job is already running: foo", and `stop foo` hangs indefinitely.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

kill timeout 90
expect daemon

pre-start script
  rm -f ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID
end script

exec start-stop-daemon \
  --pidfile ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID --chuid $USER:$GROUP \
  --exec ${HOME}/bin/run --start > run.log 2>&1
```

There's no process owned by $USER and no pidfile, so why does upstart think the daemon is still running, and how can I convince it otherwise?

Answer (score 6):

Workaround: Rename the the `foo` service to `foo2`...

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582745

Comment: I can confirm that this is true.  Short of a restart there is no practicable way to convince upstart that it's internal state is wrong.  Source: Dealt with a very complex production environment experiencing this very situation due to a bad daemon build.